# How can I append HTML within and before the text of a rendered Link Field?

Tags: mvc, links

I have a General Link field in Sitecore that I would like to append some HTML to.

I know that I can create a custom extension method and put what I want *after* the link's text by doing the following:

```
public static HtmlString CallToActionButton(this SitecoreHelper helper, string fieldName, object parameters)
{
    if (helper == null)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("helper");
    }
    return new HtmlString(helper.BeginField(fieldName, null, parameters).ToString() + " <em>text within the link, but after the default text</em>" + helper.EndField().ToString());
}
```

But what I don't know is how to include the text within the link, but before the default text.

So the above would give me:

```
<a href="https://example.com/">
  Link text defined in Sitecore
  <em>text within the link, but after the default text</em>
</a>
```

but I want:

```
<a href="https://example.com/">
  <em>text within the link, but after the default text</em>
  Link text defined in Sitecore
</a>
```

What would the extension method be to append HTML before the default link text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd basically want to override the text element in the field renderer:

Something along these lines:

```
@{
    var linkField = (LinkField) Model.Item.Fields[fieldname];
}
@Html.Sitecore().Field(fieldname, new {
    text = " <em>Before the text: </em>" + linkField.Text 
})
```

More examples: 
https://marcotanainsights.wordpress.com/2017/10/05/tips-on-using-html-sitecore-fields-parameters-object/